# AddressOf with parameter

Tags: vb.net

One way or another I need to link groupID (and one other integer) to the button I am dynamically adding.. any ideas?

What I can do;

```
AddHandler mybutton.Click, AddressOf PrintMessage

Private Sub PrintMessage(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    MessageBox.Show("Dynamic event happened!")
End Sub
```

What I can't do, but want to;

```
AddHandler mybutton.Click, AddressOf PrintMessage(groupID)

Private Sub PrintMessage(ByVal groupID as Integer)
    MessageBox.Show("Dynamic event happened!" & groupID .tostring)
End Sub
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13401246/how-to-pass-parameters-in-addhandler-using-vb-net

Answer (score 49, accepted):

There is no way to do this with `AddressOf` itself.  What you're looking for is a lambda expression.

```
AddHandler myButton.Click, Function(sender, e) PrintMessage(groupId)

Private Sub PrintMessage(ByVal groupID as Integer)
    MessageBox.Show("Dynamic event happened!" & groupID .tostring)
End Sub
```

Comment: I tried this with a Sub as shown above, and received a compilation error in .NET 3.5: "Expression does not produce a value". When setting my delegate as a Function that always returns true, it worked. WHY??

Comment: @http203 this is implementation detail of the lambda expression semantics in 3.5. Support was only added for value returning lambdas and `Sub` doesn't return a value.  This was relaxed in later versions of the language

Comment: How to call `RemoveHandler` later for this event handler?

Comment: To remove the handler: `Dim Handler = Sub(sender, e) PrintMessage(groupId)<br/>AddHandler myButton.Click, Handler<br/>RemoveHandler myButton.Clock, Handler`

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/error-messages/lambda-expression-will-not-be-removed-from-this-event-handler

Answer (score 5):

You can create your own button class and add anything you want to it

```
Public Class MyButton
    Inherits Button

    Private _groupID As Integer
    Public Property GroupID() As Integer
        Get
            Return _groupID
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Integer)
            _groupID = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Private _anotherInteger As Integer
    Public Property AnotherInteger() As Integer
        Get
            Return _anotherInteger
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Integer)
            _anotherInteger = value
        End Set
    End Property

End Class
```

Since VB 2010 you can simply write

```
Public Class MyButton
    Inherits Button

    Public Property GroupID As Integer

    Public Property AnotherInteger As Integer
End Class
```

You can access the button by casting the `sender`

```
Private Sub PrintMessage(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    Dim btn = DirectCast(sender, MyButton)
    MessageBox.Show( _
      String.Format("GroupID = {0}, AnotherInteger = {1}", _
                    btn.GroupID, btn.AnotherInteger))
End Sub
```

---

These new properties can even be set in the properties window (under `Misc`).

The controls defined in the current project automatically appear in the toolbox.

Comment: If you do not intend to use the properties for anything else than accessing a private field without restrictions, you can leave out the getter and setter.

Answer (score 2):

Use the Tag property of the button.

```
Button1.Tag = someObject
```

AddressOf gets the address of a method, and thus you cannot pass parameters to it.

Comment: I'd strongly advise against using the `Tag` property of controls. It's a maintenance nightmare; neither its name nor its static type hint at the object being referenced. If you want to follow that route, a better alternative would be to derive a subclass  `MyButton` from `Button` and add a new, properly named and typed property such as `GroupId`, then use that instead of `Tag`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use delegate which very clear for your code follow as:

**Define a delegate**

```
Public Delegate Sub ControlClickDelegate(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
```

**Custom button class**

```
Public Class CustomButton
    Inherits System.Windows.Forms.Button
#Region "property delegate"

    Private controlClickDelegate As ControlClickDelegate

    Public Property ClickHandlerDelegate As ControlClickDelegate
        Get
            Return controlClickDelegate
        End Get
        Set(ByVal Value As ControlClickDelegate)
            controlClickDelegate = Value
        End Set
    End Property

#End Region

    Public Sub RegisterEventHandler()
        AddHandler Me.Click, AddressOf OnClicking
    End Sub

    Private Sub OnClicking(ByVal sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs)
        If (Me.controlClickDelegate IsNot Nothing) Then
            Me.controlClickDelegate(sender, e)
        End If
    End Sub

End Class
```

**MainForm**

```
Public Class MainForm
    Public Sub New()

        ' This call is required by the designer.
        InitializeComponent()

        ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.

        Me.CusButton1.ClickHandlerDelegate = AddressOf Me.btnClick
        Me.CusButton1.RegisterEventHandler()
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        Me.TextBox1.Text = "Hello world"
        End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 2):

The below worked for me:

```
Dim bStart = New Button With {.Text = "START"}
AddHandler bStart.Click, Function(sender, e) TriggerProcess(any Long value)


Private Function TriggerProcess(ByVal paramName As Long) As Boolean
 ' any processing logic
 Return True
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

My solution:

```
AddHandler menuItemYear.Items(i).MouseUp, Sub() menu_year(2019)

Private Sub menu_year(ByVal intYear As Integer)
   'do something
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

There are few ways to do that depending of the complexity and number of parameters required.
1. Use Tag for adding a complex structure
2. Inherit the the Button class and add the values as class members then populate them before using it. That gives you a lot more flexibility.

If you are using web version 
3. You cannot add it to Tag, but for simple values assign it to index use .Attributes.Add("name"). This gets added to the HTML tags and not the Server side.  You can then use the index to access a server side structure for complex systems.
4. Use sessions to store values and store the session reference to Name attribute as described above (#3).

Answer (score 0):

No problem ;-)

For example:

```
Private ComboActionsOnValueChanged As New Dictionary(Of ComboBox, EventHandler)

'somewhere in function
dim del = Sub(theSender, eventArgs)
           MsgBox(CType(theSender, ComboBox).Name & " test")
          End Sub
ComboActionsOnValueChanged.Add(myCombo, del)

'somewhere else
Dim delTest = ComboActionsOnValueChanged(myCombo)
RemoveHandler myCombo.SelectedValueChanged, delTest
myCombo.DataSource = someDataSource
AddHandler myCombo.SelectedValueChanged, delTest
```

as we expect, event won't fire after DataSource change in this place