# How to pass parameters in AddHandler using VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

This is what I'm trying to do. I'm creating a dynamic check with an autoback that when clicked, will go to my subroutine and do something. The two parameters I'm trying to pass is the table which the checkox is located and the name of the id of the checkbox. But I'm getting the error

> AddressOf must be the name of a method without parentheses or
>
> method does not have a signature compatible with sender as object, e system.eventArgs". Here is my code below.

```
 chkSel = New CheckBox
 chkSel.ID = "check_" & CStr(a)              
 chkSel.AutoPostBack = True

  'This is where I get the error
  AddHandler chkSel.CheckedChanged, AddressOf change_operating_items(tableName, "check_" & CStr(a))  
 tblcell.Controls.Add(chkSel)
 tblrow.Cells.Add(tblcell)
```

Comment: thanks for the response. I didnt know if you could or not

Answer (score 6):

You cannot pass arguments when you register an event handler.

Instead you can pass them when you raise that event in case of a custom event.

Here you need to handle the `CheckedChanged` event, cast the `Sender` to `CheckBox` and use it's `ID` property.

```
Sub change_operating_items(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) 
    Dim chk = DirectCast(sender, CheckBox)
    Dim id = chk.ID
    ' do something with it '
EndSub
```

Answer (score 2):

I had to use the following to send *both* the sender, e, and the custom parameters:

```
AddHandler chart1.PostPaint, Sub(sender, e) Chart1_BottomPostPaintScorePlot(sender, e, GroupNames) 

Private Sub Chart1_BottomPostPaintScorePlot(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As ChartPaintEventArgs, ByVal GroupNames() As String)

  If TypeOf e.ChartElement Is Legend Then

    'process the legend at the bottom 

  End If
End Sub
```