# Beginner ? - event handling for multiple custom controls

Tags: vb.net, events, lambda, event-handling

Working on a Windows Forms app for employee scheduling. I have a main form with several FlowPanels, each populated with several instances of a custom control. Each custom control can raise a LMB-clicked and a RMB-clicked event. Currently, the controls in the flowpanels are in an 2-dimension array.

How do I identify which custom control was clicked?

I've looked at other threads on SO (that I can't figure out how to refer to here, but [AddressOf with parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9143385/)).

Until I teach myself the use of lambdas (which I couldn't get to work, btw, but was the only potential solution I could find), would there be other ways to solve this?

FWIW, I can recode the custom control, if necessary.

EDIT:
This is the code for the custom control:

```
`Public Class ShiftViewControl
Inherits UserControl

'Sub-class clsShiftViewData
Public Class ClsShiftViewData
    'clsShiftViewData private properties
    Private _employee As String = ""
    Private _job As String = ""
    Private _startDate As Date = New Date(1900, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0)
    Private _endDate As Date = New Date(1900, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0)
    Private _hours As Double = 0
    Private _request As Boolean = False
    Private _splitShift As Boolean = False
    Private _override As Boolean = False
    Private _notes As String = ""

    'clsShiftViewData class property statements
    Public Property Employee() As String
        Get
            Return _employee
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _employee = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Public Property Job() As String
        Get
            Return _job
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _job = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Public Property StartDate() As Date
        Get
            Return _startDate
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Date)
            _startDate = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Public Property EndDate() As Date
        Get
            Return _endDate
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Date)
            _endDate = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Public Property Hours() As Double
        Get
            Return _hours
        End Get
        Set(value As Double)
            _hours = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Public Property Request() As Boolean
        Get
            Return _request
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Boolean)
            _request = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Public Property SplitShift() As Boolean
        Get
            Return _splitShift
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Boolean)
            _splitShift = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Public Property Override() As Boolean
        Get
            Return _override
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Boolean)
            _override = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Public Property Notes() As String
        Get
            Return _notes
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _notes = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class

Public Event LmbClicked(ByRef sender As Object, ByVal e As MouseEventArgs)
Public Event RmbClicked(ByRef sender As Object, ByVal e As MouseEventArgs)

Private _shiftViewData As New ClsShiftViewData

Private Sub HandleAllClicks(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As MouseEventArgs) Handles lblEmployee.MouseClick, lblJob.MouseClick, lblStartTime.MouseClick, _
                                                                lblEndTime.MouseClick, lblHours.MouseClick, _
                                                                lblRequest.MouseClick, lblNotes.MouseClick, Me.MouseClick, _
                                                                lblSplitShift.MouseClick, lblOverride.MouseClick
    If e.Button = Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Right Then
        RaiseEvent RmbClicked(Me, e)
    Else
        RaiseEvent LmbClicked(Me, e)
    End If
End Sub



'MISC methods here

Public Sub PutData(ByVal svInfo As ClsShiftViewData)
    'Fill both _shiftViewData and corresponding form controls
    _shiftViewData = svInfo
    With _shiftViewData
        lblEmployee.Text = .Employee
        lblJob.Text = .Job
        lblStartTime.Text = .StartDate.ToShortTimeString
        lblEndTime.Text = .EndDate
        '...
        lblNotes.Text = .Notes
    End With

End Sub
Public Sub GetData(ByRef svInfo As ClsShiftViewData)
    With svInfo
        .Employee = _shiftViewData.Employee
        .Job = _shiftViewData.Job
        .StartDate = _shiftViewData.StartDate
        .EndDate = _shiftViewData.EndDate
        .Hours = _shiftViewData.Hours
        .Request = _shiftViewData.Request
        .Notes = _shiftViewData.Notes
    End With

End Sub


Private Sub ShiftViewControl_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

End Sub
```

End Class

And this is the code I'm currently working on:

```
`Imports ShiftBox    '  .dll includes custom control ShiftViewControl
```

'
'NOTE:  A lot of this code is experimenting, FYI, and I've removed some code to clarify
'

Public Class FrmShiftBoard
    Public Sv(7, 6) As ShiftViewControl     'Array will eventually be dynamic
    Public WithEvents TempSvc As New ShiftViewControl

```
Public Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    DebugMode = False
    Const rowcount As Integer = 7
    Const spacing As Integer = 15
    Const intSpace As Integer = 15
    Dim fp(rowcount) As FlowLayoutPanel
    Dim tempFillData As New ShiftBox.ShiftViewControl.ClsShiftViewData
    Dim col As Integer
    Dim row As Integer
    Dim locationPoint As New Point
    Dim newLocationPoint As New Point
    Dim tempPoint As New Point


    'Following  section is my newbie code to setup the form
    Me.Width = (TempSvc.Width * 7 + intSpace * 7)
    Me.Height = (TempSvc.Height * rowcount + intSpace * 7)
    locationPoint.X = 1
    locationPoint.Y = TempSvc.Size.Height * row
    For row = 0 To rowcount - 1
        fp(row) = New FlowLayoutPanel
        fp(row).AutoSize = True
        tempPoint.X = TempSvc.Size.Width : tempPoint.Y = TempSvc.Size.Height
        fp(row).Size = tempPoint
        newLocationPoint.X = locationPoint.X
        newLocationPoint.Y = locationPoint.Y + (TempSvc.Height * row) + spacing * row
        fp(row).Location = newLocationPoint
        Me.Controls.Add(fp(row))
    Next

    For row = 0 To rowcount - 1
        For col = 0 To 6

            'I've tried multiple variations of the following line to no avail
            AddHandler Sv(row, col).LmbClicked, AddressOf myHandler

            Sv(row, col).Name = "SV" + row.ToString + "," + col.ToString()
            Sv(row, col).PutData(EmployeeList(col).ToShiftViewFill)
            fp(row).Controls.Add(Sv(row, col))
        Next
    Next

End Sub


Private Sub myHandler() 'Handles ?
    'Here is where I beiieve I should handle the LmbClicked event
    'and determine which ShiftViewControl fired the event.  Then
    'I can branch to code based on which ShiftViewControl
    'was selected.  Maybe I should use something other than
    'an array?

End Sub
```

End Class

And I have no clue how to get the "End Class" lines into the code samples  :(

Comment: Please post your code, no matter how "newbie-ish". We can answer much better then.

Comment: It's very bad that you're just passing on the `MouseEventArgs` object from the inner event to the outer.  That object has properties indicating the position of the mouse pointer and that's relative to the control that was clicked.  That means that your control will be passing position information to the consuming code that is not accurate.  You might use the `PointToScreen` method of the child control and the `PointToClient` method of the UC to translate that data and create your own `MouseEventArgs` object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every event handler should have the same basic signature, i.e. a `sender` parameter of type `Object` and an `e` parameter of type `EventArgs` or some derived type.  The `sender` parameter refers to the object that raised the event.  That's how you always access the object that raised the event and that's how you should determine which UC was clicked in your case.

Comment: Thank you @jmcilhinney - I've edited my initial message to add current code, if that sheds any light on my question...

Comment: It's like you didn't even read my answer. I said that an event handler should have two parameters.  Does your event handler have two parameters?  No, so there's an obvious solution.  I said that you can access the object that raised the event via the `sender` parameter inside the handler.  Are you doing that?  No, so there's an obvious solution.  I've told you what to do so now you should do it.

Comment: Apologies - the uploaded code version above was before your reply.  I had altered the handler in so many ways, with no success, that night that I had reverted it back to a shell to start anew.  Thanks, again, for your insights.

Answer (score 0):

You are currently handling all of these clicks: `lblEmployee.MouseClick, lblJob.MouseClick, lblStartTime.MouseClick, lblEndTime.MouseClick, lblHours.MouseClick, lblRequest.MouseClick, lblNotes.MouseClick, Me.MouseClick, lblSplitShift.MouseClick, lblOverride.MouseClick`. This means that the `sender As Object` in the `HandleAllClicks` contains a reference to whichever control was clicked.

Then you go on to call either `RaiseEvent RmbClicked(Me, e)` or `RaiseEvent LmbClicked(Me, e)`. You are now saying that the current class (`Me`) raised the click.

Instead, if you call them like `RaiseEvent RmbClicked(sender, e)` and `RaiseEvent LmbClicked(sender, e)` then you can use the `sender` variable to determine the control that caused the original click.

Comment: Thank you, @Enigmativity.  You've shed some light on what to try tonight.  To be clear on my intentions - The custom control is just a setof labels representing a record.  When a control (shift)  is "selected" (click anywhere in control), a popup will allow editing that record.  Hence the multiple click handler.  Thought that would save memory/refresh time.  If that sounds like the wrong approach, please advise.   I’ll work on the “sender” versus “me”, as recommended now.  Thanks so much.

Comment: @JDGiants - I'm happy to offer suggestions, but I don't know what you mean by "Thought that would save memory/refresh time". There's very little need to be concerned about memory unless you have actually encountered some sort of memory exception. I don't know what "refresh time" means.

Comment: I just didn't see the need to fill 56*7 comboboxes, textboxes, etc., versus all labels.  Wouldn't that many (and presumably more in the future), take time to redraw (refresh)?  And then have just a single submodal form to edit whichever of the shifts was clicked (selected).  I'm prob way off base.  And no, no memory exceptions, just trying to avoid any future lags...

Comment: @JDGiants - I think you'd struggle to have a refresh lag or memory issues with most apps. I think you'll be fine.

Answer (score 0):

So, after a couple more hours of trial and error, and a lot of searching, I believe I've found my solution.  Here is the current (partial) code:

```
        For row = 0 To rowcount - 1
        For col = 0 To 6
            Sv(row, col) = New ShiftViewControl()
            Sv(row, col).Name = "SV" + row.ToString() + "," + col.ToString()

            'EmployeeList() - temporary list just used to generate 
            '   different records in Sv array
            Sv(row, col).PutData(EmployeeList(col).ToShiftViewFill)
            FP(row).Controls.Add(Sv(row, col))

            'This line was correct all along
            AddHandler Sv(row, col).RmbClicked, AddressOf myHandler
        Next
    Next

End Sub


'Yes, the two parameters are needed here.  But NOT needed in the 
' AddHandler line above, as I kept trying to do
Public Sub myHandler(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As MouseEventArgs)
    'This works - sender.name returns the   
    '     "SV"+row.tostring+","+col.tostring"    Name as expected
    MsgBox("myHandler" + vbCrLf + _
                        "   sender.name " + DirectCast(sender, ShiftViewControl).Name)

    'sender.name can now be parsed, giving me the array indexes
End Sub
```

And I know it's probably so simple to the experts.  Thank you for taking the time to help.  Any other critiques, comments, suggestions, please do.  Beyond that, I believe I have taken another step forward.  Thanks!